# Encountering a page load error on Android tablet but not other browsers when submitting form

Tags: jquery, loading, tablet

I have a booking form using Jquery.  The form is working fine on desktop and also on my android phone. However when I use my android tablet (Asus TF101) I get `ERROR LOADING PAGE`.  It still sends the email, but it is not directing to the thank you page.

I am using `header("Location: www.myurl.com");` to redirect.
I have also tried `window.location.replace` and `document.location.href`.

As I said, it works on desktop and also mobile phone.  The form can be found here - 
http://www.theweddingsite.com/test/formm.php

Comment: You might want to edit your subject - it looks snipped

Comment: Your page is not structured correctly (and although it may not affect this issue), it will cause you lots of pain. Use the proper html5 doctype, html, head, and body tags to ensure you are rendering in the correct standards mode. e.g. `<!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;IE=10;IE=9;IE=8,chrome=1"/><title>Page Title</title></head><body>Your Content</body></html>`

Comment: Thanks. I have added the html tags but still doesn't work. I cannot understand why it works on Android phone Galaxy S2 but not on Android tablet.

Comment: Is that PHP (`header("Location: www.myurl.com")`)? If so, it should really be `header('Location: http://www.myurl.com'); exit;`